# Fetch and Save Weather Data as JSON

Tags: java, json

This is part 2 to [Fetch, Parse, and Save JSON](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88592/fetch-parse-and-save-json). As the code evolved, I wanted to post the program with changes for review again.

The objective of the program is to fetch JSON information from a service through their API and save it. Currently, I dislike the way the program handles bad user input in the WeatherTracker class by having two similar checks with the same error message back-to-back. I'm also beginning to feel that the job of saving the data is not necessarily the responsibility of the `fetchHistoricalData` function. I'm thinking that `fetchHistoricalData` ought to return a JSON on success, and `null` on failure, and another function should save the data instead. Please let me know what you think.

Lastly, in the near future there will be a script initiated by a cron job that will call this program with changing parameters at set intervals of time. I need a way for this program to exit on failure in such a way that a top level script can catch it and stop running. The only way I know how to do this now is with `Sys.exit(#)`, but is this the best way?

Please feel free to be pendantic/critical. I would like to be able to submit this as an example of side projects I've done to future employers with confidence :D

Main Class

```
public class WeatherTracker {

    private static final String RESPONSE = "response";
    private static final String HISTORY  = "history";
    private static final String ERROR    = "error";
    private static final String INVALID_OPTION = "Invalid option. Please use option -h or "
                                                 + "--help a list of available commands";
    private static final String USAGE_MSG = "WeatherTracker -k [api_key] -f [feature] [-options]\n"
                                            + "Query Wunderground for weather data.\n The 'k' option must "
                                            + "be used for all feature requests";

    public static Boolean validData (JsonNode node) {
        return node.get(RESPONSE).get(ERROR) == null;
    }

    public static void saveDataAsFile(JsonNode node, String dirPath, String fileName) 
            throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        File dir = new File(dirPath);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Could not make file at " + dirPath);
            } 
        }

        File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(file, node);
        System.out.println("File created at: " + file);
    }

    public static boolean fetchHistoricalData(String apiKey, String city, String state, String date, String savePath) 
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        // Do not attempt to get historical data unless all parameters have been passed
        if (city == null || state == null || date == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("City, State, and Date must be provided when requesting historical data");
        } 
        else {
            JsonNode json = new WundergroundData(apiKey).fetchHistorical(city, state, date);

            if (validData(json)) {
                //Files and full path will be saved in the format of ${savePath}/${city}/${date}.json
                String dirPath = String.format("%s/%s", savePath, city);
                String fileName = String.format("%s.json", date);

                saveDataAsFile(json.path(HISTORY), dirPath, fileName);

                return true;
            }
            else { 
                System.out.println(json.get(RESPONSE).get(ERROR));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException {

        String feature  = null;
        String city     = null;
        String state    = null;
        String date     = null;
        String apiKey   = null;
        String savePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        //Initialize and set up CLI help options
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("f", "feature", true , "Feature requested");
        options.addOption("p", "path"   , true , "Location to save file (defaults to current working directory)");
        options.addOption("c", "city"   , true , "City requested");
        options.addOption("s", "state"  , true , "");
        options.addOption("d", "date"   , true , "Format as YYYMMDD. Date of look-up when doing a historical query");
        options.addOption("k", "key"    , true , "Wunderground API Key");
        options.addOption("h", "help"   , false, "Show help");

        //Initialize CLI Parsers
        CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();

        // Parse CLI input
        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

        // Set CLI input to variables
        if (cmd.hasOption("f")) { 
            feature = cmd.getOptionValue("f");
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("p")) {
            savePath = cmd.getOptionValue("p") ;
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("c")) { 
            city = cmd.getOptionValue("c");
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("s")) { 
            state = cmd.getOptionValue("s");
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("d")) { 
            date = cmd.getOptionValue("d");
        }
        if (cmd.hasOption("k")) { 
            apiKey = cmd.getOptionValue("k");
        }

        // Main entry point
        if (cmd.hasOption("h") || args.length == 0) {
            new HelpFormatter().printHelp(USAGE_MSG, options);
        }
        else if (cmd.getOptionValue("k") != null) {
            if ("history".equals(feature)) { 
               fetchHistoricalData(apiKey, city, state, date, savePath); 
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(INVALID_OPTION);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(INVALID_OPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

API Interface Class

```
public class WundergroundData {
    private static final String PROTOCOL = "Http";
    private static final String WU_HOST = "api.wunderground.com";
    private String apiKey; // Wunderground requires a registered key to use services

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public URL featureUrl(String feature) throws MalformedURLException {
        // Standard Request URL Format: ${protocol}${WU_HOST}/api/${key}/${features}/${settings}/q/${query}
        return new URL(PROTOCOL, WU_HOST, String.format("/api/%s/%s", apiKey, feature));
    }

    public JsonNode fetchHistorical(String city, String state, String date)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readTree(featureUrl(String.format("history_%s/q/%s/%s.json"
                                                                     , date, state, city)));
    }

    public WundergroundData() {
    }

    public WundergroundData(String key) {
        setApiKey(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I got to say is wow this is already cleaner now! Nice changes!

Comment: @Marc-Andre Thanks! I had help from good people :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one suggestion for starters...

### nesting-`else`

When a method is strictly doing only one thing or another:

```
private T method(Object... args) {
    if (condition) {
        // do something for true
    } else {
        // do something for false
    }
}
```

You don't need the `else` and the extra level of indentation. I will actually recommend this especially for cases where the code block can get a bit long. Therefore, you can can improve your main method as such:

```
public static boolean fetchHistoricalData(String... ) 
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    if (city == null || state == null || date == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
    }
    // no need for else here and the extra indentation
    JsonNode json = new WundergroundData(apiKey).fetchHistorical(city, state, date);
    ...
}
```

This also applies for all `if`-blocks that are *returning* from either branches...

```
JsonNode json = new WundergroundData(apiKey).fetchHistorical(city, state, date);
if (!validData(json)) {
    System.out.println(json.get(RESPONSE).get(ERROR));
    return false;
}
String dirPath = String.format("%s/%s", savePath, city);
...
return true;
```

In this case, I flipped the clauses around since the code for handling invalid JSON data is a little shorter.

And finally for your `main()` method:

```
if (cmd.hasOption("h") || args.length == 0) {
    new HelpFormatter().printHelp(USAGE_MSG, options);
} else if (cmd.getOptionValue("k") != null && "history".equals(feature)) {
    fetchHistoricalData(apiKey, city, state, date, savePath);
} else {
    // final catch-all
    System.out.println(INVALID_OPTION);
}
```